# Why I can't delete a user object this way?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, function, react-hooks

**Hello Everyone !**

I'm new to ReactJS, and I'm trying to do some simple projects to get the basics.

I started a little project consisting at adding and deleting user of a list with React Hooks (manipulating the state).

I can properly add a new User to my Userlist and display it, but when it comes to delete a user, nothing happened.

**I found the solution, but I can't explain it, that's why I'm asking for your help !**

Here is my App.js file with the DeleteUser function that **works**

```
import style from './App.module.css';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import UserList from './components/UserList';
import UserForm from './components/UserForm'

let USERS = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'John',
    age: 27
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Mark',
    age: 24
  }
]

const App = () => {

  const [userss, SetUsers] = useState(USERS);

  const AddNewUser = (user) => {
    SetUsers((prevList) => {
      let updatedList = [...prevList];
      updatedList.unshift(user);
      return updatedList;
    });
  };

  const DeleteUser = user => {
    SetUsers((prevList) => {
      let updated = prevList.filter(el =>  el.id !== user.id);
      return updated;
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className={style.root}>
        <UserForm liftUpNewUser={AddNewUser} />
        <UserList users={userss} liftUpUserToDelete={DeleteUser} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**My Question is:**
Why does the DeleteUser function writtten this way (below) doesn't work ?  Knowing that it is the same logic as the AddNewUser function.

```
const DeleteUser = user => {
    SetUsers((prevList) => {
      let updated = [...prevList];
      updated.filter(el =>  el.id !== user.id);
      return updated;
    });
  };
```

Sorry in advance for my english!
Hope someone can help me =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line in your code...

```
updated.filter(el =>  el.id !== user.id);
```

... is a no-op, as value of `updated` array never gets changed. `filter` *returns* [a new array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) instead, and this new array gets assigned to a variable in the first snippet.

The side effect of this is that React won't have to compare those arrays by value: their references will be different. It wouldn't have been the case if `filter` worked the way you expected it to work, making the changes in-place, similar to Array.splice.

Answer (score 0):

Because `Array.filter` method does not modify the original array but returns a new one.